# Who is linking to my blog?

Tags: untagged

How can I determine the sites that are linking to a post within my blog? Or even just my blog in general?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics is another extremely useful tool which is free to use. Google Analytics is displayed to visitors using JavaScript, so search bots and most spam bots etc. which do automated page requests but don't use JavaScript won't be counted (which is a good thing). In this way Google Analytics can give a better representation of the human visitors to your sites than log-based stats programs.

Answer (score 11):

In Google you can type "link:http://stackoverflow.com" (for example) to find all the indexed links to your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you use wordpress in Blog Stats you can see Referrers. Referrers are other people pages that contain links to your blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS then your log files can record the field cs(Referer) which will show when someone has come to your site via an external link...

Answer (score 0):

[Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) let you see who's linking to you without invasive analytics of any kind.